# CSS row border bottom

Tags: css, html, row, border

For my website I have split the page up into rows using CSS(no tables) to get a line to split up the content. As you can see ive just used height:px; for each row to manually move the line. But it jumps all over the place in different browesers. Is there a way to get it to automatically set the border so it appears at the end of the content inside the div?

```
 .row1A
{
    height: 600px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.row2A
{
    height: 820px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

<div class="row1A">
            <div class="column1">
            <h2> Bluerock FX-10G</h2>
            ***Content***
            </div>
                <div class="column2">
                <img src="Images/Amps/Bluerock.jpg" alt="Bluerock FX-10G" width="450px" height="325px">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row2A">
                <div class="column1">
                <h2>Line 6 Spider IV 15W</h2>
         ***Content***
                </div>
                    <div class="column2">
                    <img src="Images/Amps/Line6Spider.jpg" alt="Line 6 Spider IV" width="350px" height="350px">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your HTML mark-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding following styles:

```
 .row1A
{
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    clear:both;
}
.row2A
{
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its fixed it for the browsers but for some reason it has taken the final row border on each page and put it up the top which has also moved the footer to the wrong place...

Comment: @user3095599 To remove border from last row use `.row1A:last-child, .row1A:last-child {border-bottom:none;}`

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed thanks for your help. For some reason when i entered the extra info above the border was at the top of the row not at the bottom. Maybe it was like that anyway just did not make a fuss. But i have now fixed it by removing the border from row 1.